# win10 - run dir command in cmd too slow

Tags: windows-10

I am using win10. when I try to run a dir in cmd.exe. it's very slow to scroll the files on the screen. The file list will be scroll on screen looks like a animation effect added (not sure). I wish to get a quick result. linux's terminal more better to response ls result per my experience.

How can I speed up cmd.exe screen update speed?

Refer to [this](https://github.com/wjj1928/sharefolder/blob/master/screenrecord.mp4?raw=true) link for screen record when I run dir command!

Comment: “ I wish to get a quick response but do not do any animation!” - Please clarify what you mean exactly by editing your question

Comment: I just listed a 42,000 character text file with the TYPE command and it was like lightning. DIR on Windows\System32 was just about as fast. I could see it listing but not slow and not anything to be concerned with. I have Kali and Ubuntu here and I do not perceive a big difference in the operating systems.

Comment: Thanks, please help check my screenrecord when I run dir command. maybe something wrong with my computer! I have updated the link above!

Comment: Your video looks normal. Nothing slow there. Writing to a console is slow. It wasn't a big list. If you dir a large tree it takes a bit of time till the folders are in the disk cache.

Comment: if you just want the result quicker, you can just redirect the output to a file. then view the file with your choice of text editor.

Comment: Seems slow... was it always slow? What are you computer specs? Does your GPU need an update?